# Number of bound variables does not match number of tokens with query builder

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, query-builder

I have the following query:

```
...
$now = new \DateTime('now');
$now->setTime($now->format('H'), 0, 0);

$shopsQueryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('shops')
  ->select('shops.id, shops.fullname, shops.username')
  ->leftJoin('shops.owner', 'owner')
  ->leftJoin('owner.location', 'location')  
  ->leftJoin('location.city', 'city')           
  ->leftJoin('city.state', 'state')         
  ->leftJoin('state.province', 'province')
  ->where('shops.expirydate >= :expiryDate')
  ->setParameter('expiryDate', $now);

if ($provinceId)
{
  $shopsQueryBuilder->where('province = :province')
    ->setParameter('province', $provinceId);
}

if ($stateId)
{
  $shopsQueryBuilder->andWhere('state = :state')
    ->setParameter('state', $stateId);
}

if ($cityId)
{
  $shopsQueryBuilder->andWhere('city = :city')
    ->setParameter('city', $cityId);
}
...
```

I wonder why I keep getting the error:

> Number of bound variables does not match number of tokens with query builder

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `andWhere` here:

```
      if ($provinceId)
      {
          $shopsQueryBuilder->andWhere('province = :province')
                  ->setParameter('province', $provinceId);
      }
```

Otherwise, you're replacing the `where` clause for `shops.expiryDate`, rather than adding to it. And it still has the parameter for that field.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to set the property owners and use andWhere method, something like this:

```
...
$shopsQueryBuilder
    ->andWhere('city.province = :province')
    ->setParameter('province', $provinceId);
...
```